# excel convert the whole number to decimal places

Tags: excel

I have a problem with excel. The problem is that, when I insert a whole number, excel converts it to decimal number. How to fix this in excel?

For example, if I insert 3, then excel converts it to 0.03.

Comment: Never can happen it. Clear cells format if any. Check is there any macro running which can convert it. Did you try to a new workbook?

Comment: @Harun24HR Thank you for your comment. Yes, I try to open new workbooks many times. However, I face the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `File -> Options -> Advanced` and clear `Automatically insert a decimal point` checkbox under `Editing options`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to excel. I always work with R. Thank you again.